# Pattern for handeling multiple message types with spring JMS in a multi module maven setup

Tags: spring, module, jms, activemq-classic, jms-topic

I' m currently investigation the implementation of queue's or topic, based on activeMQ within our project. The setup is pretty straight forward in which we are using maven modules to seprate business logic according to the business domain. One common module allows us to assemble common logic.

simplified Example:

- common module
- products module
- clients module

One of the requirements is that certain operations are asynchronous towards a backend (by means of a activeMQ) which in turn responds with a result message.
The second requirement is that it should be possible to horizontally scale the application by creating a new deployable artifact with only that module that needs more juice.

We are using spring 4 with of course jms and activeMQ.

On to my question. We would like to use just one queue or topic for backend connectivity. Which would mean our common module would handle jms configuration (jms factory, jms-configuration) and different types of messages will be send over that one queue/topic.
How would can I make sure that product related messages get handled by the "products" module and client related messages get handled by the "clients" module? How can I make sure only one of the "products" modules logic would handle a message if the module was deployed two times? What approach would you recommend or is this one queue/topic "nuts"?

I was myself thinking in the direction of using a topic because of the publ/subsc pattern... , or maybe queue listener acting as publisher in a observer pattern to which product- or client subscribers might subscribe to take over handling the message?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why using a Topic if you want just one of the "products" modules to handle one message? With Topic you'd have one message - multiple subscribers each getting the message. The Queue ensures only one consumer gets a message (point-to-point), with Topic you'd have one message dispatched to all subscribers.

Regarding the "filtering" of messages, this should be something provider specific. Looking at ActiveMQ docs I see [this](http://activemq.apache.org/selectors.html). So, basically each consumer should get the messages the broker, based on selector, will dispatch. I don't know the specifics, but this would be the first place I would start this investigation.
On the same idea, have a look at [this discussion](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/jms/114028-jms-adapter-content-based-filtering) from the Spring forum. It is, indeed, related to Spring Integration, but it's on the same idea of message selection. On the other hand, you could consider adopting Spring Integration in your project: it's kind of an abstraction of integration patterns and fits well with everything message oriented.

Few interesting ideas from that forum post:

- `JmsTemplate` from Spring contains a `doReceive` method that [takes as a parameter a String as message selector](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html#doReceive-javax.jms.Session-javax.jms.Destination-java.lang.String-)
- Message selectors are in the [JMS spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/jms/Message.html) (scroll down to "Message Properties" section)
- Relevant section in the Spring Integration documentation is [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#jms-selectors)